# flutter: reading List<Object> from shared prefs results in Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Object>'

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I'm currently able to write a List of Objects to shared preferences using JSON, but so far am unable to read in the same way.

Currently I have:

```
  List<PAOData> paoData;
  String spKey = 'test';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSharedPrefs();
  }

  Future<Null> getSharedPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getKeys().contains(spKey)) {
      print('found existing');
      setState(() {
        paoData = json.decode(prefs.get(spKey));
      });
    } else {
      print('setting to default');
      setState(() {
        paoData = defaultPAOData;
        print(json.encode(paoData));
        prefs.setString(spKey, json.encode(paoData));
      });
    }
  }
```

The first time this is run, the list of objects is properly converted into a string of JSON, and successfully written to storage. Thereafter, it finds the key and attempts to read but fails to convert (`Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<PAOData>'`). I figure I have to do something like below, but not sure about syntax and such.

```
paoData = json.decode(prefs.get(spKey)).map((x) -> {
  PAOData.fromJson(x)
  });
```

The data class looks like:

```
class PAOData {
  String digits;
  String person;
  String action;
  String object;
  int familiarity;

  PAOData(this.digits, this.person, this.action, this.object, this.familiarity);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'digits': digits,
    'person': person,
    'action': action,
    'object': object,
    'familiarity': familiarity,
  };

  PAOData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    digits = json['digits'].cast<String>();
    person = json['person'].cast<String>();
    action = json['action'].cast<String>();
    object = json['object'].cast<String>();
    familiarity = json['familiarity'].cast<int>();
  }
}
```

Comment: `List<PAOData>.from(json.decode(prefs.get(spKey)))`

Comment: As a side note, there's no need to cast to primitive types (`String`, `int`, `double`, etc.) unless you know there's a possibility for it to come in as something different. i.e a `double` and you want it as an `int`.

Comment: thanks for the response. with your change I get `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'PAOData'`

Comment: i also removed the casting

Comment: and I can confirm the JSON it reads looks good. `print(json.decode(prefs.get(spKey)));` results in `[{digits: 00, person: Ozzy Osbourne, action: rocking out a concert, object: rock guitar, familiarity: 0}, ...]`

Comment: `List<PAOData>.from(json.decode(prefs.get(spKey)).cast<String, dynamic>())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206324/discussion-between-matt-takao-and-supposedlysam).